# c++ Compiler could not generate operator= for class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, reference, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

This code:

```
struct TToken
{
    UnicodeString &DBIDs;
    std::vector<TToken> T;
    TToken(UnicodeString &DI) : DBIDs(DI) {}
    void Append(void) {T.push_back(TToken(DBIDs));}
};

UnicodeString DI="25,40,55";
TToken T(DI);
if (T.DBIDs==DI) // if I comment out this comparison it works fine
....
```

generates the above compiler error (I'm using C++Builder 10.1 Berlin).

If I change the `UnicodeString` reference to a pointer, it all works as expected. Does anyone know why the reference generates the error?

By the way, is there an easier way of making `DBIDs` available to every created `vector` element instead of passing a pointer/reference all the way down the line? A `static` member is no good, and I did look at template expressions, but couldn't get an acceptable answer.

Comment: One question per question please. Your compiler cannot generate `operator =` because a reference is not assignable.

Comment: I don't think that's right Quentin. I've used the correct notation for initialising a reference member. If I comment out the bottom == line then it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Isn't your question title wrong then? I looks like you're asking about `operator==` not `operator=`.

Comment: I can't say you're wrong zett but the title is the exact error returned by the compiler.

Comment: @NoComprende: Quentin is correct.  A reference cannot be reassigned after it has been declared. A reference member can only be initialized in a constructor, it cannot be changed in an assignment operator. That is why the compiler cannot generate a default `operator=`. `push_back()` requires `T` to be copyable. That being said, in this code there is no reason for `DBIDs` to be a reference/pointer at all, since the character data of `UnicodeString` is reference-counted.  So just pass around `DBIDs` by value, there will only be one copy of the character data in memory

Comment: What's the `.....` contained in the `if` block? Does it have an assignment? Otherwise I can't see how this code would generate the error you claim.

Comment: Mark, the ... was an unrelated line that I used to stop the debugger.

Comment: Remy, thanks very much. I never knew that about UnicodeString. After I posted this I was wondering why I didn't go straight to the embarcadero forum.

Comment: Mark, you're correct. ... was T=T which was in fact the offending line.